# Ether.li transfer problem

Tags: wallets, contract-invocation, balances, ether.li

I still can't transfer my Eth's from Ether.li to another account.

> “Please fund your user account with sufficient ether (~0.01 ETH / tx) for gas (transaction fees)“

That's what the site tells me to do and after i tried to transfer it like that, but then it tells me "must specify a amount).

I would be very happy if someone can help me, and i'm ready to pay the one out.

Comment: Welcome. Still? You might be more successful if you provide more details about what's going on. What happened before? What site? Screen pictures, etc. Anything that helps the answerers understand what you're trying to do, and the present situation.

Answer (score 3):

Ether.li uses a multi-signature contract wallet. To access funds on the contract wallet, you need to have a small amount of Ether on the *user account* (one of the owners, not the wallet) to pay the gas for the contract execution.

So send a small amount (0.1 ETH) to that account rather than the wallet and you will be able to execute that contract and withdraw funds from the wallet.

Comment: I've tried to sent some ETH to my User Account within Ether.li, but since I don't already have any ETH in my User Account I'm not able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to buy ETH and send it to your etherscan.io account. After that you're able to send your ETH from ehter.li!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solve it with sending ETH to my Account. Then I was able to send my Ether.